# Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, corda

I am using version 4 of Corda.

Following is the code displayng versions of platform and other dependencies:

```
cordaReleaseGroup=net.corda
cordaVersion=4.0
gradlePluginsVersion=4.0.45
kotlinVersion=1.2.71
junitVersion=4.12
quasarVersion=0.7.10
log4jVersion =2.11.2
platformVersion=4
slf4jVersion=1.7.25
nettyVersion=4.1.22.Final
```

Following is the version of springboot webserver -

```
buildscript {
    ext.spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    ext.spring_version = '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    ext.spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    ext.slf4j_version = '1.7.25'
    ext.log4j_version = '2.9.1'
}
```

Nodes get deployed and run successfully but error is thrown when springboot webserver is run.

Following error is thrown while running the springboot webserver -

```
W 14:54:44 1 AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
I 14:54:44 1 AnnotationMBeanExporter.destroy - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
I 14:54:44 1 StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
I 14:54:44 1 ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
E 14:54:44 1 SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at net.corda.server.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:37) ~[main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method 'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$StandardGsonBuilderCustomizer.customize(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.lambda$gsonBuilder$0(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.gsonBuilder(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b.CGLIB$gsonBuilder$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e08927ea.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b.gsonBuilder(<generated>:65535) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$StandardGsonBuilderCustomizer.customize(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.lambda$gsonBuilder$0(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.gsonBuilder(GsonAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b.CGLIB$gsonBuilder$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e08927ea.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$65ee490b.gsonBuilder(<generated>:65535) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have `gson` version `2.6` or higher

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.6'
```

You can use `gradle dependencies` command to check dependencies graph.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I was using old version (2.3.1) of gson.

After updating the version to 2.6, the webserver ran successfully.